# Compare integers and strings PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Need to capture two variables via POST.

If they are different integers, save $mensalidade = 4 and a integer and any other state save $mensalidade=8.

I try this but dont work..

```
if (is_int($_POST['linha_ida']) != is_int($_POST['linha_volta'])) {

   $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=4;

} else  {

   $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=8;
}
```

Broke a little more head and now it's perfect! 
Thanks to all

The code looked like this

```
if($linha_ida === $linha_volta || preg_match( '/[A-Z]/' , $linha_volta )|| preg_match( '/[A-Z]/' , $linha_ida )){
    $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=8;
    }  else{
    $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=4;
}
```

Comment: `is_int` tests if a string contains an integer. It will return a boolean. So you are only testing if one POST value is an int while the other is not.

Comment: `is_int()` returns `true` or `false` if the parameter is an integer or not. If you compare `is_int($iamaninteger)` to `is_int($iamanintegertoo)`, you compare `true` and `true`, not your variables' values. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `(int)` parser to convert the string to an integer.

```
if ((int)$_POST['linha_ida']) != (int)($_POST['linha_volta']) && is_int($_POST['linha_ida']) && is_int($_POST['linha_volta']) {

    $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=4;
} else  {
    $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=8;
}
```

Taken from the Question comments from caCtus

> caCtus:
>   is_int() returns true or false if the parameter is an integer or not. If you compare is_int($iamaninteger) to is_int($iamanintegertoo), you compare true and true, not your variables' values.

Comment: i may be wrong but i think code as currently posted will save 4 for two none-integers e.g.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_int($_POST['linha_ida']) && is_int($_POST['linha_volta']) && $_POST['linha_volta'] !=  $_POST['linha_ida']) {
   $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=4;
} else  {
    $mensalidade= $_POST['mensalidade']=8;
}
```

Comment: Downvoters: The questioner wants to check if both `$_POST['linha_ida']` and `$_POST['linha_volta']` are integers and if their values are different.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped! exactly that! I used only INT