# LIMIT clause similar to the MySQL in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I must execute the query below in PHP with SQLServer, however I can not use the missing `LIMIT` clause in Microsoft queries.

```
$SqlTabelaAtual="SELECT * 
            FROM BusinessCadTabPreco
            RIGHT JOIN BusinessCadTabPrecoItem ON BusinessCadTabPreco.CdTabela = BusinessCadTabPrecoItem.CdTabela
            WHERE  BusinessCadTabPreco.CdEmpresa =01
            AND CdProduto =".$row['CdProduto']."
            ORDER BY  BusinessCadTabPreco.DtSincronizar DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Use TOP. That is the sql server statement for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code, in **SQLServer** the keyword **Limit** is **TOP**

```
$SqlTabelaAtual="SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM BusinessCadTabPreco
            RIGHT JOIN BusinessCadTabPrecoItem ON BusinessCadTabPreco.CdTabela = BusinessCadTabPrecoItem.CdTabela
            WHERE  BusinessCadTabPreco.CdEmpresa =01
            AND CdProduto =".$row['CdProduto']."
            ORDER BY  BusinessCadTabPreco.DtSincronizar DESC"
```

Comment: ;) Thank u too @denis

Comment: If this worked for you please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This will help other people who encountered the same issue, as well as rewarding rdn87 for his/her effort.  Could you also review these past questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934508/compare-integers-and-strings-php) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538070/run-an-audio-file-instantly-when-clicking-on-the-application-button-android).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the records returned by adding the TOP expression to your [SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) clause.

**Usage**

```
/* Returns the first 10 records.  
 * Combine with an ORDER BY if you want control over the records returned.
 */
SELECT TOP 10
    Id
FROM
    TableName
;
```

Or

```
-- Percent return.
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT
    Id
FROM
    TableName
;
```